# "I am being used as a communication tool..."

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

The question **[I am being used as a communication tool between 2 project teams who refuse to help each other out](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80440/i-am-being-used-as-a-communication-tool-between-2-project-teams-who-refuse-to-he)** was closed for being a rant without a question. It's true that there was no actual question statement, but I think the scenario makes a good topic here, so I added a one-line question at the end to focus the answers. I would like to nominate the question to be reopened.

Comment: Possibly better to answer your own question and mark it as accepted rather than just editing the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has received enough votes to be reopened.